# TortoiseGit: add to ignore already commited gen and bin folder

Tags: git, gitignore, tortoisegit

How to add to ignore list already commited gen and bin folder using TortoiseGit?

Comment: Do you want to ignore new changes, or to stop tracking those files at all?

Comment: "Do you want to ignore ..."   -  second one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For untracking + ignoring files, you do:

```
$ git rm -r --cached gen/ bin/
$ echo "gen/" >> .gitignore
$ echo "bin/" >> .gitignore
```

`git rm --cached` removes the file from the index, without changing the file in the working copy. So now git doesn't track it, but you still have it in your local folder.

Comment: this is the better answer

Answer (score 5):

resolved myself:

1. add folders to **.gitignore**
2. delete these folders
3. commit , push

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

With TortoiseGit do as following for each item:

```
1. Right click on item -> TortoiseGit -> Delete and Add to ignore list
2. Select "Ignore item resursively" for Ignore Type. Select ".gitignore in the repository root" for Ignore File or just make it your choice.
3. Commit item. Commit .gitignore file
```

Comment: the question is on the tracked items. 
but your answer is useful for the untracked items.